# Javascript onclick after returning a partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

How can I use a javascript onclick function like

```
$('#resultTable tbody tr').on('click', function () {
```

on an element (in this case table) that is returned in partial view?

Comment: Do you mean an element that is loaded after the page is initially rendered (i.e. using ajax)?

Comment: yes, it is an element loaded after the page is initially rendered

Comment: `$(closestAncestorThatExists).on('click', dynamicallyAddedElement, function() { .... });`

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great!